# Is $\mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0\}$ dense in $\mathbb{R}$ in its usual topology?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

I am trying to prove disprove the following statement. This problem occurs in the Biglist of Topology which I am trying to solve by myself.

> $\mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ in its usual topology?

I think it is dense in ℝ. The reason being that we can approximate any real number to arbitrary closeness even without zero.

Also, what about a finite set of points from $\mathbb{Q}$. Is there an infinite set of points that we can remove from $\mathbb{Q}$ that leaves the resulting set dense?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}\backslash\{0\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku I think it is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. The reason being that we can approximate any real number to arbitrary closeness even without zero.

Comment: FYI, if $A$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ and $F$ is a finite subset of $A,$ then $A-F$ is dense in ${\mathbb R}.$ To see this, use the "infinitely many points in every neighborhood" formulation of the limit point of a set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A = \mathbb{Q} - \{0\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. To show $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, we show that $\bar{A}$, the closure of $A$ in $\mathbb{R}$, is equal to $\mathbb{R}$ (here, $\mathbb{R}$ taken in its usual topology). Since $\bar{A} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we only need to show that $\mathbb{R} \subseteq \bar{A}$.

We will use without proof (relatively simple) the fact (*) that between any two real numbers $a, b$ with $a < b$ there exists a rational number $c$ such that $a < c < b$.

Take arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{R}$. A basis element for the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ has the form $B = (a, b) = \{y \in \mathbb{R} | a < y < b\}$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. Consider an arbitrary basis element $B_0 = (a_0, b_0)$ containing $x$; then $a_0 < x < b_0$. There are a couple cases.

(1) If $0 \notin B_0$, then (*) provides that there exists a rational number $c_0$ such that $a_0 < c_0 < x$; clearly $c_0 \ne 0$ so $B_0$ intersects $A$.

(2) On the other hand, if $0 \in B_0$, then $a_0 < 0 < b_0$. Here consider $x$. If $x < 0$, then just as before, (*) provides rational $c_0$ such that $a_0 < c_0 < x < 0 < b_0 \implies c_0 \ne 0$, so $B_0$ intersects $A$. If $x = 0$, (*) still provides rational $c_0$ such that $a_0 < c_0 < x = 0 < b_0 \implies c_0 \ne 0$, so still $B_0$ intersects $A$. Finally, if $x > 0$, (*) guarantees a rational $c_0$ such that $a_0 < 0 < x < c_0 < b_0 \implies c_0 \ne 0$, so once again $B_0$ intersects $A$.

In any case, $B_0$ intersects $A$, so $x \in \bar{A}$, and we have shown that $\mathbb{R} \subseteq \bar{A}$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks! Perfect Answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a lemma

> If $X$ is a topological space and $A$ is a subset of $X$, then $A$ is dense in $X$ if and only if $A$ intersects every open set other than the void set.

The proof is trivial: Consider $X\setminus A^-$, which is an open set that does not intersects $A$. It is void if and only if $A$ is dense.

Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb R$, it is obvious that $U\cap \left(\mathbb Q\setminus\{0\}\right)$ is non-void.